# Ants vs zombies game

Tags: java, variables, methods, project

I am working on a GUI-less tower defense game with zombies and ants. My problem is with one of the ants. It is supposed to reflect half (rounded down) of the damage done to it back to the zombie. This is my code for the ant and a sample zombie.

```
package proj4;

public class ThiefAnt extends Ant {

    private int taken;

    public ThiefAnt(){
        super(15, 25, "Thief Ant");
    }

    public void takeDamage(int amount, Zombie z){
        setLife(amount, z);
        taken = amount / 2;
    }

    public void attack(Game g){
        Zombie z = g.getHorde().elementAt(0);
        z.takeDamage(taken);
    }
}

package proj4;

public class GiantZombie extends Zombie implements Gigantic {

    public GiantZombie() {
        super(40, 20, "Giant Zombie");
    }

    public void attack(Game g) {
        Ant a = g.getColony().elementAt(0);
        a.takeDamage(35, this);
    }
}
```

My problem is with the taken variable. For its `setLife` the parameter amount works fine and the ant takes damage according to the amount. But for the taken variable, setting it to `amount` does nothing and it just contains 0. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't an implementation like this reflect the damage better:

```
public void takeDamage(int amount, Zombie z){
    setLife(amount, z);
    z.takeDamage(amount / 2);
}
```

Comment: Lol yes it does. I have been stuck on this part for hours and you solved it in minutes. Thank you very much!